# Reparing ubuntu installation using usb drive

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, package-management, boot-repair

I upgraded from ubuntu13.04 to ubuntu 13.10 and the process went very bad. Many packages were broken because my internet connection failed and now, when I turn my computer on, it is very slow and many features don't work (like the internet or mounting external media). 
I tried rebooting with dpkg. It says many packages are broken, but I have no way to repair them. I would like to avoid reinstalling it completely since I cannot create a backup for my data (no external drive would mount). Is there an easy and safe way to repair broken packages using a usb drive during the boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to easily fix all your broken packages is to boot on an Ubuntu 13.10 usb drive, choose `Try Ubuntu`, then follow [this procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation) from the Ubuntu community documentation.